# Iterating a Dictionary and Typescript to create content

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to react and I've been trying to figure out an issue.  I have content being sent to me by an API and I read it in then run a map() function on the object(s) to generate the content. For example:

```
const content = data.products.map((product) =>
        <Link to={`/product/${data.id}/`}></Link>
);
return(
<div>
   {content}
</div>
);
```

Now I have the exact same scenario with the API i'm pulling data from except the object being return is a dictionary. Here are the types and the map() that isn't working:

```
export interface Product {
    [key: string]: {
        stats: ProductData;
    };
}

export interface ProductStats {
    id: string;
    product_data: {
        products: Product;
    };
    team_id: string;
}

const content = data.product_data.products.map((product) =>
        <h1>do some stuff here</h1>
);
return(
<div>
   {content}
</div>
);
```

What would be the best way to render out the "{content}" in this scenario?

I've tried using Object.entries(),it does output an array of the strings for the productIds. However, I can't seem to get that to work. For example I've tried this:

```
    const content = Object.entries(data.product_data.products).map((productId) =>
            <h1>do some stuff here data.product_data.products[productId]</h1>
    );
```

[Link to Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgZRmmEMxgGc4BvAKDkQBMAuOcmKZAcztZjPID6DMphakKAERE0AvjRqhIsRCjRZcBPpJHUeYKBAYBXbBRYAFA8dPlZ8xdHjJUGHHkuGTFXfXoBtAGtgAE8WNg4kTgBdFlpfeN5+MS1yAG4eehl0uQVwRxUXdTxxSji4TmAkNEwAGxYAcUrqmrsHZWc1NzhGqqhan3KwFiQjAFsAIzQ7GnQjJFMECCRNYik+AAoASl0eADdMKHKARgamvpq4AF5qQZYjuCy9g-KAJlPe-uuqW7h7x-p9odyCdNPwrjcKh86scHukAc9yG9Qd4vuUzrUWJwXrCnocwCCPNYUQN4gAiI4vADMABZSbFEmZWH8ADQZXyk6mUl5HOk3NhJVjYmSszK41gMEElNaYcHffSeGwsfH-OCA1jA5LEEqyxgsclHHnMhmCYR8MISnE8bBLNhwa2qFDggDy4wAVsBTAA6SrsBDAcjrcjAz38ihCESe+VE8ibT2jTBgdbrKNeACSDG2lwAfGyEnAADwAGWQATgREuVAABgB6FOmasAEiodZg6ZklZkWe+QaOIZS4b4kasXnIfhb6aiff4nshzRnYAe+erxaQARz9E26R4UGAMCMUGW6zZ+YYCF264S1erZYAFghKAwIP6kAByeA7vcHuCYJDBGB3yIAH5cxue1UEdOR4iXU9zx4TdpjaeAGGALAjBqeBCFWER0iAA) Here is a sample of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: We can't actually see what the data is. If it's an object, `Object.entries` will return the object entries. Unclear what's "returning void".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  `Object.entries()` definitely doesn't return `void`.  Please consider providing a [mre] others can paste into their own IDEs so that people can test any answer before suggesting it.

Comment: We still don't know what the actual data is. The "what I tried" edit adds the literal string `"data.product_data.products[productId]"` to the `<h1>` content; I'm not sure what "it doesn't work" means here.

Comment: Please review the guidelines for [ask] and what makes a [mre].  Take your code here and paste it into some standalone IDE (maybe [The TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play)).  See all the errors that you're not asking about?  You need to fix those.  Like, what's `data`? What's `ProductData`? Etc.  Once you fix it so that the only problems remaining are the ones you actually want to ask about, then take that plaintext and paste it here (not just the URL to an IDE).  Then people can help you.

Comment: @DaveNewton added link to sample.

Comment: @jcalz added link to sample.

Comment: `Object.entries(ss1.stats_data.products)` works fine in that example once it's runnable.

Comment: @DaveNewton it might return a list of keys, but what i"m trying to accomplish is return the html based on those values. I must be missing something. I've updated the example:

Comment: Could you please re-read my previous comment, specifically the part about the example needing to be here, in plaintext?  And note that the link you've presented has multiple compiler errors that you're not asking about.  You really need to make sure the only errors your code has are specifically relevant to the question, or else they are at best distracting. Perhaps [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NDdGRN) is what you're looking for, but you need to clear up whatever's going on with `Link` before I'd be comfortable keeping this question open. Please [edit] to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Object.keys(objectName).map

Here is a basic example:

```
export interface Product {
    [key: string]: {
        stats: { name: number, age: number};
    };
}

const products: Product = {
   corn: {
    stats: { name: 1, age: 1 }
   },
   rice: {
    stats: { name: 2, age: 2 },
   },
   grapes: {
    stats: { name: 3, age: 3},
   },
};

Object.keys(products).map((product, index) => {
    console.log('Render the product stats:', products[product].stats);
});
```

I don't know what the shape of your data is but this is the general idea. You'll need to call Object.keys.map(objectName) on the object that you want to map through and then you will need to use the key from the map to access that object from products.

I'm not sure if this was just a typo, but there also aren't JSX braces {} around the content you want to be displayed.